# Instead of dataGridView in C# windows application, what should I use for console application to display a table from sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, console

Question as above. I was told to use list<> to do so, but I still have no clue about how to do it exactly. I am new to C#.

Comment: You could delimit your data and print one row per line with `Console.WriteLine();`

Comment: Actually I already create a stored procedure for "select" the certain columns as what I want to display. This point is I need to use the query I wrote.

Comment: There is no control you can bind to a console like the DataGridView for a Window Form.  You will have to tell the console exactly what to print.  So, that means looping through the data returned from the SQL query to your C# application and row by row telling the console what to display.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, jradich1234. Could you mind giving me some example code for demonstrating the way to print line by line? Let me simply say for example there is a table RestaurantMenu with column ID, Dish and Price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the very simplified example below...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(***Your Connection String Here***);
conn.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select ID, Dish, Price From RestaurantMenu", conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.fill(dt);

conn.Close();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){

     console.WriteLine(dr["ID"].ToString() + " | " + dr["Dish"].ToString() + " | " + dr["Price"].ToString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing what jradich1234 did is the most practical approach. You fill a dataset with the table data and then just go through it printing each line and then adding a \n after the last column.

If you really want to use the list<> object (or you have to do it), then the proccess has a little more of work. Basically you have to create the list and then, instead of printing, you add a new item to the list that represents the row... and then you move through the list and do exactly the same jradich1234 did.

It is a good way to practice the use of lists and simple structs, but it is not as efficiend as the previous answer.